# Android Studio repository cannot be enable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, repository

I was try to set up the proxy setting to "Auto Detect Proxy Setting", but it still cannot be enable, please help me to find the other solution for this problem

[image]

Comment: Try to provide a specific proxy setting instead of auto detection.

Comment: Thank You for your question :D

Answer (score 0):

I use hotspot shield proxy and it works fine. also psiphon does the job but you have to set it to tunnel all traffic